# How to increase iPhone volume programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

In my app I have to play the siren sound on tapping the button, I can able to play it when ringer volume is set to some value, but my problem is when user kept their ringer volume to zero, how can I play it with maximum sound?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase volume programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138180/increase-volume-programmatically)

Comment: but if i do it in that way,my app get rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code ,it only work in device

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:setvalue];
```

Comment: Its working but volume UI appearing in this condition. Could you please provide me any solution to remove this volume UI.

Answer (score 1):

Officially you can't do this. As a smartphones user, I wouldn't appreciate to set my volume at 10% and have an app that rings at max volume.

You can however try to use `Celestial.framework`, but your application will be rejected from the App Store.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your response.but i don't want to go with this.